# Convert letters to lowercase without toLowerCase()

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to convert letters into lowercase and i'm using a for loop and without using .tolowerCase. I'm not sure but it's not working... Here is my code..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String a1 = "apple";
    char[] s1 = a1.toCharArray();  

    for (int i=0; i<s1.length; i++)
    {
        int CharNumber = s1[i] - 'a';
        int NewChar = (char) CharNumber;
        char[] NewNew = Character.toChars(NewChar);
        System.out.println(NewNew);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may simply treat each character as integer and add 32 to any character whose ASCII integer value be less than or equal to 90.  This would convert uppercase to lowercase letters, leaving lowercase letters as they were.

```
String a1 = "aPplE";
char[] s1 = a1.toCharArray();
int diff = 'a' - 'A';

for (int i=0; i < s1.length; i++) {
    if (s1[i] >= 'A' && s1[i] <= 'Z') {
        s1[i] += diff;
    }
}

System.out.println(s1);

apple
```

### Demo

Comment: 90? Really? How about only converting actual letters and how about making code more self-explanatory by using character literals? I.e. `if (s1[i] >= 'A' && s1[i] <= 'Z') { s1[i] += 'a' - 'A' }`

Answer (score 0):

Found an efficient approach, which could be of help. Please refer this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/RewrotethetoLowercasemethodtoimproveperformances.htm

```
public class Main {

  private static final char[] LOWER_CASE =
      { 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0, '-',   0,   0, 
          '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 
          '8', '9',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 
          'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 
          'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 
          'x', 'y', 'z',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 
          'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 
          'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 
          'x', 'y', 'z',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
            0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0 
      };

  public static final String toLowerCase( String value )
  {
      char[] chars = value.toCharArray();

      for ( int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++ )
      {
          chars[i] = LOWER_CASE[ chars[i]];
      }

      return new String( chars );
  }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you find useful in the website as links might change

Comment: Neat solution, but note that the function will destroy any other characters than 0-9A-Za-z.

Comment: Yes it will. But we can always modify the code according to our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This should Work :

```
     private static String  toLowerCase(String inputWord)
          { 

        StringBuilder inputW = new StringBuilder(inputWord);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < inputW.length() ; i++)
            { 
         // check for Capital  letter ...   ascii code of "A" is 65 ... "Z" is 91.
            if(inputW.charAt(i) >= 65 && inputW.charAt(i) <=91)   
                {
                 //   The character at the specified index is set to  to uppercase
                    inputW.setCharAt(i, (char)(inputW.charAt(i)+32));    
                }
        }
        return inputW.toString();
    }
```